# Store checkbox value in sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox, session-storage

Can any one help me I'm trying to store the state of checkboxes by using `window.sessionStorage`. When the user goes from page1 to page2 and then click back button to go to page1 I want all the checkboxes which the user checked before going to page2 to be checked.

This link have the script at the bottom of the page which work once it is in  the localStorage or sessionStorage mode
http://elikirk.com/store-form-data-with-html5-localstorage-and-jquery/.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using localstorage?

Comment: Yes because using local storage ...it stores the data across all the browsers I want to clear the sessionStorage as soon as the browser/tab  is closed

Comment: Ok, well try to use .setItem() or someting else explained on the link I posted, otherwise it should be something in your code, that would be searched... If its possible give me a JSFiddle of it, so I can debug it better

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe its the way you using the sessionstorage...

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Here is a link where localstorage and sessionstorage are explained

If not, please post a JSFiddle of your complete code (if possible), so I can debug your code...

Comment: This does not answer the question, or even attempt to answer it, and is nothing more than a `link only answer`

Comment: Bad reference, see [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)...  Using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a better reference.

Comment: Sweet, well you have recognized that Microsoft is the only one whos not part of the HTML5 movement and even the whole IE is badly updated with common features? But MDN is better than any other Website?!? :-) Just a hint repeating waste, posted on websites nobody realy reads aint a good advice

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I have resolved it by myself.

```
   $('#id of the form').submit(function (ev) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('checkBoxesResult', $("#id of the form").serialize()); 
  });

if(sessionStorage.getItem("checkBoxesResult")) {

        var printVal = sessionStorage.getItem("checkBoxesResult");
        var checkBoxArray = [];
        if (printVal != null) {
        checkBoxArray = printVal.split("&");
        for( var i=0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++ ) {

            var nv  = checkBoxArray[i].split("=")
            n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]),
            v = nv.length > 1 ? decodeURIComponent(nv[1]) : null;

            selectedChkBox(n,v);
        }
    }
    }


   function selectedChkBox( chkbox, value ) {
      $("[name="+chkbox+"]").each( function() {   
     if ( $(this).val() ==  value )
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
     else
        if ( $(this).attr('checked') == true)
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
     }
```